# Azure Powershell script throwing 'Forbidden'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a powershell script that is throwing error. I am trying to create an Alert Action Group through powershell. The last line is throwing error.

```
$TenantId = Get-AzTenant | select Id
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $TenantId.Id -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName


$Receiver1 = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name $ActionGroupReceiver -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress $EmailAddress
Set-AzActionGroup -Name $ActionGroup -ResourceGroup $Rg -ShortName $ActionGroupShortName -Receiver $Receiver1
```

[image]

I have Owner access to the subscription and can confirm that all of these variables have appropriate values.
The same code worked for a different subscription in the same tenant where I have contributor access. This is probably an access issue however I am not able to figure why I am getting Forbidden even with Owner access.

Edit - Error text
Set-AzActionGroup : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message:
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.ActionGroupsOperations.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.ActionGroupsOperationsExtensions.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.ActionGroupsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdate(IActionGroupsOperations
operations, String resourceGroupName, String actionGroupName, ActionGroupResource actionGroup)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.ActionGroups.SetAzureRmActionGroupCommand.ProcessRecordInternal()
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.MonitorCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet(), Code: Null, Status code:Null, Reason
phrase: Null
At C:\Users\YashTamakuwala\Desktop\live_traffic\Alerts\Alerts\CreateActionGroup.ps1:25 char:1

- Set-AzActionGroup -Name $ActionGroup -ResourceGroup $Rg -ShortName $A ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzActionGroup], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.ActionGroups.SetAzureRmActionGroupCommand
  ```

Comment: Hi.  It would be best to share your error message as text rather than an image.  I googled "Set-AzActionGroup" "forbidden" and got these two results [another thread on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117522/set-azactiongroup-exception-type-errorresponseexception) and [one on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/11526) there were a few different solutions.  Maybe they will help.

Comment: Made the edit. Thanks for responding. I am attaching at ResourceGroup Level. Not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I tried performing the same action through portal but couldn't. Got this error. [image]

There were policies in place to prevent such activities. Also, the requests from powershell are tracked in Activity Logs which in hindsight, I should have looked into. So I temporarily disabled the policies and was able to run the script successfully.

Comment: Great! I deleted the answer because it does not apply to your situation.